# Is it okay to have lots of classes in android program?

Tags: android, performance

I am developing an android application, and this application going to have lots of classes ( maybe 30 or more ). Will this slow down my application or is it a bad programming method?
I would be glad if someone can answer this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

30 classes is definitely not considered "a lot". Most of the applications I develop for Android have about 100-200 classes.

This doesn't usually impact the application's runtime performance. If anything, it might slow down the compiling process, but this doesn't usually affect the decision making when writing code (no-one says "oh boy, the compile time is 5 seconds longer, better rethink my entire design").

Actually, spreading your code into multiple classes is usually the best way to go, if the division of code makes sense.

Things that will hurt the performance of your app usually involve wasteful loop iterations, deep recursions, etc.

Comment: Modularizing to a point is a good idea, but modularizing every single thing is a bad idea, try to group things together through encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

My application is using 6 external libraries and apart from that I have 52 class files. Nothings seems to be creating any problem for me.